# ComboBox e SQLReader

Tags: c#, sql

Eu tenho um `ComboBox` com uma lista de items que contém nomes que são gerados a partir do meu banco de dados(eu puxo o nome da `coluna` **cerveja** que estão alocadas na tabela):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
   conexao.Open();
   SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select Cerveja from Cervejas where Cerveja ='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'", conexao);
   SqlDataReader DR;
   DR = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
   if (DR.HasRows)
   {
     while (DR.Read())
     {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(DR.GetString(0));
     }
   }
   else
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Não tem cervejas no nosso banco de dados!");
   }
```

A partir desse código eu consigo obter o nome da coluna "Cervejas" no combobox ao iniciar o programa. O que eu preciso fazer agora, é quando o usuário selecionar um item no combobox, o mesmo faz uma comparação com o nome do item do combobox e as cervejas no banco de dados, puxando a row da cerveja certa, eu estava tentando assim, porém não consigo:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            conexao.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Cervejas where Cerveja ='" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'", conexao);
            SqlDataReader DR;
            DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (DR.Read())
            {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == DR.GetValue(1))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("teste");
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("teste2");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            conexao.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Erro de conexão Modbus: \n\n" + ex.Message);
        }
```

No caso, nesta parte:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == DR.GetValue(1))
{
   MessageBox.Show("teste");
}
```

Eu faço esta comparação, se o item selecionado corresponder a alguma cerveja no banco de dados deveria imprimir a palavra 'teste', porém isso não acontece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A verificação com o `if` era ***desnecessária***, uma vez que eu uso a **cláusula** `WHERE` no `cmd`.

Apenas editei:

```
SqlDataReader DR;
DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (DR.Read())
{
     Messagebox.Show = DR.GetValue(0).ToString(); // teste
}
```